# Remove "steamclean" application

Tags: applications, macbook-pro, security

Through my high school I have a Macbook Air. Because I am the technologically curious person that I am, I found a workaround for installing apps by putting them in the package contents of other apps (i.e. Google Chrome). I did this with Steam. After doing this, they found out about it and cleared out all of the apps' package contents.

They don't specifically know that I did this, but now every time I restart my computer a pop-up comes up saying that I don't have permission to run "steamclean".

[image: Screenshot of steamclean error]

I really don't want this to come up if they are trying to help me with my laptop if I have issues with it. Any suggestions?

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan Here's the screenshot: [link](http://i1308.photobucket.com/albums/s618/bojo1498/ScreenShot2014-11-03at104448_zpsfbd0777d.png)

Answer (score 3):

Open the Terminal application and type (or copy and paste) the following command and hit ENTER. This will remove the steamclean job and should stop those popup messages.

> launchctl remove com.valvesoftware.steamclean

You may also want to run the following command to check for other Steam related launchd jobs.

> launchctl list | grep steam

On my own Mac there is another called "com.valvesoftware.steam.ipctool" that you may also want to remove.

Comment: Seems like the problem is still happening... Here's a [link](http://i1308.photobucket.com/albums/s618/bojo1498/ScreenShot2014-11-03at104448_zpsfbd0777d.png) to a screenshot of it.

Comment: It still seems to be happening...

Comment: What do you get back if you run `launchctl list | grep steam`?

Comment: Nothing happens...

Comment: Long time later, but if you look at ~/Library/LaunchAgents you may see the plist file for valve software. In my case I remove that and the problem is gone. FWIW.